# How do you change the font size in RMarkdown for Knitr

Tags: r, fonts, knitr, r-markdown

I created a Knitr document and I want to adjust the font size for the text that is NOT in the chunks. It currently appears too small and want to increase it.

Currently I am just writing a line like this:

```
Example text
---------
```

And that will make it larger but I can't control the font size. This is for an HTML document

Comment: if the output is PDF you can use the `fontsize: 12pt`. Or a more sophisticated way to include a latex package like `anyfontsize` in the YAML front matter.

Comment: what if it is an HTML document @SabDeM

Comment: Is your source .Rmd or .Rnw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .Rmd files, you can affect the HTML header size using different numbers of `#` characters, instead of the alternative underlined form which only gives you H1 and H2 sizes in HTML.  The # syntax gives you H1 - H6.  Note that this is not a knitr issue, bur rather an attribute of Markdown.  As explained [here](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#headers), these correspond in the following way:

```
# H1
## H2
### H3
#### H4
##### H5
###### H6

Alternatively, for H1 and H2, an underline-ish style:

Alt-H1
======

Alt-H2
------
```

Works in StackOverflow markdown too, at least until H3:

### This is H2

#### This is H3, smaller "font size"

Comment: No problem, happy to help.