# Change font size in RMarkdown PDF

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

How can i change the font size of PDF output in RMarkdown? 
The font to be changed is not in the chunk.
Example:

````
---
title: "Example"
author: "Tales Martins"
output:
   pdf_document:
    toc: TRUE
    number_sections: TRUE
---
\newpage

```{r, include=FALSE, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)

```
# Introduction
This is my introduction
````

How can I change the font size of "This is my introduction"?
Default font is little in PDF output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've found some posts that may answer your question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30446905/rmarkdown-font-size-and-header) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653557/how-do-you-change-the-font-size-in-rmarkdown-for-knitr). [Rmarkdown reference](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) guide has useful information also.

Comment: Thanks you, man. The solution was really very simple. It was just a bug in my head :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?:

```
---
title: "Example"
author: "Tales Martins"
output:
   pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: yes
linestretch: 1.5
---
```

Add in the YAML `linestretch: 1.5`, after that
change this `toc: TRUE` to this `toc: true` and `number_sections: TRUE` to `number_sections: yes`

An example here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEdLL.png

also you can select linestretch: 2 and others

Answer (score 0):

The PDF is formatted through a TeX engine, so you could just start your document (after the `{r setup}` block) with usual TeX font size commands, i.e.:

```
\tiny
\scriptsize
\footnotesize
\small
\normalsize
\large
\Large
\LARGE
\huge
\Huge
```

and switch back and forth to your default document size (e.g. `\normalsize`) throughout your document.

The answer lies in TeX formatting, not RMarkdown itself. Many problems are solved by passing arguments to the TeX preamble (which Rstudio calls "header"), e.g.:

```
header-includes:
  \setmonofont{Menlo for Powerline}[Scale=0.65,Color=darkgray]
```

and many problems are created by using tabs instead of spaces, with the default RMarkdown engine, knitr.